# SQL helper class - two connection strings

Tags: c#

I have the following SQL helper class:

```
public class SqlHelper
    {
        SqlConnection cn;

        public SqlHelper(string connectionString)
        {
            cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        }

        public bool isConnection
        {
            get
            {
                if (cn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                    cn.Open();
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
```

I also have two connection strings:

```
string connectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};User ID={2};Password={3};", Variables.setDb1ServerName, Variables.setDb1Name, Variables.setDb1User, Variables.setDb1Password);
string connectionString2 = string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};User ID={2};Password={3};", Variables.setDb2ServerName, Variables.setDb2Name, Variables.setDb2User, Variables.setDb2Password);
```

What I want to do is create two buttons that will check if the respective connection is active.

My attempt is below - button one:

```
private void txtConnection1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};User ID={2};Password={3};", Variables.setDb1ServerName, Variables.setDb1Name, Variables.setDb1User, Variables.setDb1Password);


            try
            {
                SqlHelper helper = new SqlHelper(connectionString);
                if (helper.isConnection)
                    MessageBox.Show("Конекцијата е успешна", "Порака", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Порака", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

        }
```

I've also create a second button, that connects to `ConnectionString2` with `SqlHelper helper2 = new SqlHelper(connectionString);`

The code compiled alright. But I'm getting errors in the actual usage. One of the connections is diagnosed as active, while the second one produces a error.

Why question is.. can I reference two connection strings to a single sql helper class? If yes, any ideas where I might be making a mistake?

Update:

[image]

So this is the error that I am receiving. But if I restart the application and try the same connection first, I will be receiving a positive indicator.

Comment: Of course you can. Why it doesn't work depends on the exact error message you receive, but you didn't post that so we cannot help you

Comment: If you are going to have a SqlConnection in a class like that it should implement IDisposable.

Comment: Post your actual error message, and show us your final connection string.

Comment: Most of the time rather than persisting connections like that the best thing to do is simply create them on demand, there is internal pooling so its more performant than you might expect.

Comment: I've updated the question. What puzzles me is that if I restart the application and test the same connection string, but as a first try, rather than as a second I will receive a positive message box.